# Encountering GeneralException RichApi.Error in Office Add-in using Excel API: An internal error has occurred

Tags: javascript, excel, office-addins

I'm developing an Office Add-in using the Excel JavaScript API and I've encountered a problem when the Excel workbook is shared using Excel's **legacy share** feature. All calls to `context.sync()` fail with a `GeneralException` error.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```js
await Excel.run(async function (context) {
    // Get the current workbook name property
    const workbook = context.workbook.load("name");

    // Sync to get the loaded properties
    await context.sync();

    debugger;
    
    result = workbook.name;
});
```

When I run this code in a shared workbook, I receive a `GeneralException` error at the `context.sync()` line. It doesn't seem to matter what I 'load' any context.sync() results in the same error.

I have confirmed that **Toolbar / Review / Unshare Workbook** fixes the problem.

Looking for a way the add-in can check and inform user. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.